# HTML Table showing Days with different events

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I know just enough about PHP and HTML to get me in trouble.  I'm trying to build a report with occurrences in 4 different places over the course of a day.  So at 7:10 there may have been an alarm for 3 minutes in one facility, and at 7:12 there might have been one for 7 minutes at another.  Each facility would have its own column.  So 4 columns across, and the events in each column lining up to the respective positions on the timeline vertically.

I'm probably over thinking this, but I'm getting nowhere.  Would each column be broken up into 86400 units with the 3 minute event spanning 180 rows?

I can't think of another way for them all to line up vertically on a grid for each individual place.

The information is in a MYSQL table with dateTime,Location,Event for simplicity sake and I'm generating one day at a time.

Comment: (1) What is your question?  (2) Don't store events in columns, store them in rows.  (3) Show some sample data.

Comment: I can certainly post the code I've been playing with, but it's a mess and accomplishes nothing other than wasting your time reading it unfrotunately.  My issue is with the items lining up in the columns across the grid.  Eg. 7:10 in one column, 7:10 in another, and 7:12 in the third.

Comment: See normalisation. A database table is NOT a spreadsheet!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Wrapper `Div` and `for each` row (if you Insert your data as rows) you can create an `inner Div` with a `margin-left` style like this:
first a css style for `Div`s

```
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
}
.inner-div {
    position:absolute;
}
```

now the `php` and `HTML` codes that creates a chart of today's events assuming that you stored events in rows and have an active connection of `mysqli` with `php` through `$link`:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<?php
$today = mktime(0, 0, 0);   //get today's timestamp
$query="SELECT * FROM Table_name WHERE event_time_stamp > " $today; //a query that gets today's events
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){    //get each row
    $margin=$row['event_time_stamp']-$today; //minus today's first second time stamp from event timestamp to calculate the distance of event from start time of each day
    echo '<div class="inner-divs" style="margin-left:'.$margin.'px;">';
    echo 'Sample Text of your Event data';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: explaining your Database structure would be helpful

Comment: Not really, no. He's asking how to display the data, not to how to structure his database. Plus, he's already explained what his basic Db setup was:
 The information is in a MYSQL table with dateTime,Location,Event for simplicity sake and I'm generating one day at a time."

Comment: The positioning really helped me get where I needed to go, and in about 1000 less lines of code.  Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Your approach seems very complex and, based on the info you provided, kind of unnecessary. Why not break down each day into 24 main rows, corresponding to each hour of the day, and then show all events occurred within that hour sorted in an ascending way based on start time? Each event could also contain more information, such as duration, etc.

Something like this, perhaps:

[image]

Comment: This is where I was headed, but I ended up breaking the day into 86400 rows based on seconds, checked each place for an occourance at that second, and the duration, which I used as the rowspan value for the table.  If there was nothing in the row across all the properties, I just didn't print the row.  It worked, but it seems very convoluted and messy.

Comment: The layout I suggested is only for displaying the info only. You can still run your checks on a per-second basis, but present it to the viewer/user in a more friendly way. I hope that makes sense. In any case, and if I got you correctly, I think your question is about how you can simplify your approach.